# JNDI datasource and ApplicationModule tester

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an ADF application module and I have it configured to use a JNDI datasource (e.g., JNDI name = `jdbc/ORCL`).

That all works fine, but when I try to test my Application Module through the integrated tester in JDeveloper (i.e., run the application module directly instead of running a page), it cannot find the JNDI data source, even if my integrated Weblogic Server is started.

Is this just a drawback of using JNDI: that you cannot use the integrated application module tester anymore?  Or is there a way to configure JDeveloper to make this all work together (JNDI + integrated AM tester)?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the default JDBC url, i.e. `java:comp/env/jdbc/ORCL` instead of using the short form `jdbc/ORCL`. Many features of JDeveloper rely on the full url to work. For example, even if you don't manually create the datasource on your Integrated WebLogic Server, you still can right-click and run a page to test because behind the scene, JDeveloper automatically create a temporary datasource with that name to run the application.

When you deploy your application to an actual standalone server, the application will automatically trim the `java:comp/env/` portion of the full url and look for the datasource with the name `jdbc/ORCL`. You don't need to shorten it yourself :).